# Image size of X pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction. How do i fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi i have a dataframe that i would like to plot using a bar and line graph.

Without the plt.text(), the graph works fine, however, when i introduce plt.text() to the graph, it says that the Image size of 2864591x628 pixels is too large.
"It must be less than 2^16 in each direction."
What i would like is the labels to be shown above the line and bar chart, but i cant seem to get it to show up.

My dataframe looks like this

```
Day             Cost    Clicks
0   2022-07-20  8.17    37
1   2022-07-21  12.02   56
2   2022-07-22  15.30   96
3   2022-07-23  14.86   117
4   2022-07-24  16.44   145
5   2022-07-25  1.13    3
6   2022-07-26  0.00    0
```

My dtypes of the dataframe:

1. Day       datetime64[ns]
2. Cost             float64
3. Clicks            int64

My code:

```
x  = df['DayDate']
y1 = df['Clicks']
y2 = df['Cost'] 


plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))


plt.title('Cost to Clicks', fontsize = 20, fontweight='bold')


plt.xticks(fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 20)


plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 20)


plt.grid(axis = 'y')
    

for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.text(i,y1[i],y1[i], ha='center', va='top',fontsize=15, color='darkblue')
    plt.text(i,y2[i],y2[i], ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=15, color='red')


plt.bar(x,y1,color='cyan')
plt.plot(x,y2,color='red',marker='o')

plt.legend(['Cost','Clicks'], fontsize=15)
```

> The code line

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  plt.text(i,y1[i],y1[i], ha='center', va='top',fontsize=15, color='darkblue')
  plt.text(i,y2[i],y2[i], ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=15, color='red')
```

Breaks the graph, and will show me the error, if i remove this, it will work, however the data labels will not be displayed. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

I would like it to show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiZFl.png)

Comment: Errr, your plot comes out over 1km in length if 2864591 pixels @ 72 dpi.

Comment: The error is quite clear. Why do you want to add those texts? Please, show current and desired output (may be generate it with just your first 100 rows to avoid the error and share the output).